# How to upgrade project from Windows SDK 8.1 to Windows SDK 10

Tags: c++, windows, version

Visual Studio 2022 don't include Windows SDK 8.1. I have old project, which use SDK 8.1, but my programs runs on Windows 7 and higher, it means they could be compiled with SDK 10. But they need to use an older version of Visual Studio - 141 or 142, because of back comaptibility with older version of AutoCAD SDK.
But when I change Windows SDK version in project properties (see picture below), the compiler is still finding windows SDK 8.1. I try to hard change WINVER in all loaded libraries to 0x000A, but then compiler doesnot find many system libraries (eg. windows.h).
What is the rigth way to change Windows SDK version regardless to old version of Visual Studio.[image]

Comment: I *think* that programs built using the Windows 10 SDK and the latest VS tool-sets just won't run on Windows 7. You can install the "VS 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)" toolset but, IIRC, you have to do that via a VS2019 installation. I use this and the "Version 7" SDK to build 32-bit apps that are compatible with XP.